# Other PaaS similar to Cloud Foundry

Tags: open-source, cloud-computing

Is there was any other Open Source [platform (PaaS)](https://www.cloudfoundry.org/) similar to [Cloud Foundry](https://www.cloudfoundry.org/) left ?

By similar I mean :

- Lets developers deploy artifacts (jars, gems, whatever) and letting the platform handle "containerization" internally. Platforms that do not force developers to learn [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). In short : *[Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)-like*.
- Supports multiple technologies (Java, Ruby, Go, whatever) and extensible
- Runs on  multiple cloud providers or on premise

OpenShift v2 had a cartridge system similar to CF buildpacks, but OpenShift v3 became [docker centric](https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-v3-platform-combines-docker-kubernetes-atomic-and-more/).

Lattice was CF light, but it's [clearly deprecated](http://lattice.cf/) according to their site.

Comment: The most appropriate tag would have been `paas`.